# React w/ Apollo & Drupal nodeQuery - how to define/pass variables?

Tags: graphql, drupal-8, react-apollo, apollo-client

Using GraphQL with React and Drupal is pretty interesting but there is scant documentation on making it all work together. This nodeQuery that pulls articles by tag works nicely but I haven't seen any examples defining how to pass variables to a nodeQuery that is defined using gqlClient. I place variable placeholders in this query but I got an error saying:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): GraphQL error: Variable "$limit" is not defined.
GraphQL error: Variable "$offset" is not defined.
```

Has anyone had success with this?

```
import gqlClient from "../gqlClient";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
export const articleListByTerm = gqlClient.query({
  query: gql`
    {
      nodeQuery(
        limit: $limit
        offset: $offset
        filter: {
          conditions: [
            { operator: EQUAL, field: "type", value: ["article"] }
            { operator: EQUAL, field: "status", value: ["1"] }
            { operator: EQUAL, field: "field_tags.entity.vid", value: ["tags"] }
            {
              operator: EQUAL
              field: "field_tags.entity.name"
              value: ["thiphif"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ) {
        entities {
          entityLabel
          entityBundle
          ... on NodeArticle {
            body {
              value
            }
            fieldImage {
              url
            }
            queryFieldTags {
              entities {
                entityId
                entityLabel
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
});
```

Here is how the query is called. You can see I am trying to pass the variables, hoping they would just work but no luck.

```
articleListByTerm({
      variables: { offset: 0, limit: 10 },
    }).then(({ data }) =>
      dispatch(receivePostsByTerm(data.nodeQuery.entities))
    );
```

Comment: read about graphql passing variables - query syntax matters

Answer (score 0):

alright - i found a the answer:

```
import gqlClient from "../gqlClient";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
let limit = 10;
let offset = 0;
let type = "article";

export const articleListByTerm = gqlClient.query({
  variables: { limit: limit, offset: offset, type: type },
  query: gql`
    query($limit: Int!, $offset: Int!, $type: String!) {
      nodeQuery(
        limit: $limit
        offset: $offset
        filter: {  .... etc ...
```

I hope this helps someone. Definitely helps me. I added a String! variable to the example to help as well. IDK if you can do an array. It was a fairly straightforward solution, just that it isn't documented in any single place. I pulled bits and pieces and guessed and finally figured it out.